# Java script / html / nav Hamburger is not working properly with ID's - menu doesn't close

Tags: javascript, html, menu, ids

I'm working on my very first webpages. The navigation bar consists of 5 sections/links (3 pages) - 1st page contains 3 links with ID's within one page + the are two linked simple pages. With two simple pages the hamburger menu works without any problem - it opens after clicking at hamburger, when I click on any section, the navigator closes automatically. The problem is when I click on the menu in the page, where the three ID's are. The navigation bar opens, the webside moves into the point where the ID is, however the navigation bar doesn't close. Please see below attached the code. Could you please help? thank you

```js
let menu = document.querySelector(".menu")
let menuIcon = document.querySelector(".menu-icon")
menuIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let iconSrc = menuIcon.src
  console.log(iconSrc);
  let splitIconSrc = iconSrc.split("/")
  console.log(splitIconSrc);

  let imgName = splitIconSrc[splitIconSrc.length - 1]

  if (imgName == "hamburger.png") {
    menuIcon.src = "img/krizek.png"
    menu.style.left = "0px"
  } else {
    menuIcon.src = "img/hamburger.png"
    menu.style.left = "-120%"
  }
})
```

```html
<nav>
  <img class="menu-icon" src="img/hamburger.png" alt="">

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="index.html#about-me">O mně</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#offer">Nabídka</a></li>
    <li><a href="instructions.html">Návody</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Galerie</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html#contact">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: When you link to a hash on the same page, it just scrolls to that ID without reloading. So unless you add click handlers to the `<a>` elements to close the hamburger menu, it stays open.

Comment: thank you for explanation and the  code Barmar, I copied it in my html...however it's not working (I use VS Code). Do I assume correctly, it goes in there?